# Use multiDexEnabled without Gradle but Eclipse build process instead

Tags: android, eclipse, android-gradle-plugin, dex, android-multidex

Since the latest SDK version, its much more simple to create applications with multiple dex files ( https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html ), my question is, can this new feature also be used when I'm not using Gradle for the build process but the "old" Eclipse build chain?

The "multiDexEnabled true" in the Gradle build file must be transmittible to the Android compiler also in other ways?

Comment: what is the solution?

Comment: I didn't find any yet :/

Comment: Here you have, a method for do it using ANT: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27903059/enable-multi-dex-option-in-ant-for-android

Comment: Now that they speeded up the build system and have support for the NDK in Android studio I recommend to switch to the new system

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue. 
So I use the following workaround. Have added 'android-support-multidex' to lib folder and update 'dependecices' tag in gradle in next way

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar', exclude: 'android-support-multidex.jar')
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'}
```

I hope this will be useful for you.