# Android - Multidex using Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook, ant

Just started working in a new company that've been developing an app for some time now. They really like here using 3rd party open-source libraries and yesterday i got the dreadful message

> Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
>   Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536

when tried to add facebook sdk. We are still working on eclipse (on mac) here and the last day i've been breaking my head on implementing the multidex solution as described [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html).
Since im not using gradle i had to workaround this problem and found a nice solution - [Enable `--multi-dex` option in ant for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27903059/enable-multi-dex-option-in-ant-for-android).

The problem i'm having now is with executing build.xml ant script with the multidex additions. I cannot understand which target i need to execute by default, and whether i should do it everytime i want to launch the app from eclipse (just for debugging). i tried to execute the debug target but im getting the following message :

> /Applications/adt-bundle-mac/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:601: The following error occurred while executing this line:
>   /Applications/adt-bundle-mac/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:653: The following error occurred while executing this line:
>   /Applications/adt-bundle-mac/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:698: null returned: 1

As you can see im kindda helpless here. i would really appreciate some guidance with the way of working with multidexed applications on eclipse. Thanks!

Comment: some answer for this question?

Comment: Eclipse Andmore is adding support for MultiDex. https://github.com/eclipse/andmore/pull/97