# Configuring Your App for Multidex without Gradle

Tags: android, android-multidex

I get this while adding the external lib in my app project.

```
Conversion to Dalvik format failed:
Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
```

I found a solution for this using gradle here
https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html#mdex-gradle

I want to give a support to my app without gradle. Does any one have achieved it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MultiDex without gradle could be an issue.
I've tried that and its a pain, check out what [facebook](https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-engineering/under-the-hood-dalvik-patch-for-facebook-for-android/10151345597798920) did.
Its a lot work, it was easier for me to switch to gradle.

Answer (score 1):

you can try to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27903059/enable-multi-dex-option-in-ant-for-android) "tutorial" described by michalbrz:

I have tryed it, but its just pain...
If you have a choice, whether to implement multidex in ant or to migrate to gradle (which supports multidex almost nativley), I would recomend you to take the second option.
The reason is not only the complexity of introducing multidex in ant. Another problem is, that the mainDexClassList is very statik in this way (because you have to write it by yourself). So upgrades wont be compfortable.